# Check if method is false then output results

Tags: php, class

I have a class that contains a method which carries out various database checks. It then returns the value, if exists.

Here is a very basic setup example:

**PHP Class**

```
class myClass{

   var $aVar1;
   var $aVar2;

   function myMethod() 
   {
       // database query
       // if results from query return **results**
       // else return false
   }

}
```

**HTML/PHP File**

```
// setup $myClass object var

<?php if($myClass->myMethod(): ?>
    // lots of html
    <?php echo $myClass->myMethod() ?>
    // lots of html
<?php endif; ?>
```

This occurance happens multiple times throughout my file with different `methods`. My question is, I am calling the method initially and checking if it's false and then calling it again to `echo` the output.

I could do the following but would end up with a variable declaration on every method. There must be a more professional approach?

```
<?php 
$myMethod = $myClass->myMethod();
if($myMethod): ?>
    // lots of html
    <?php echo $myMethod ?>
    // lots of html
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there a cleaner more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: How about $result = $myclass->my method(); then if ($result) { lots of html } else query failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Age old problem. One common technique is to store the return val in a temporary variable

```
$result=$myClass->myMethod();
if($result!=FALSE)
  echo $result;
```

You can also use a simpler version

```
if($result=$myClass->myMethod())
echo $result;
```

And you can also use the simplest one!

```
echo $myClass->myMethod() ?: '';
```

Simpler than the simplest one!

```
echo $result=$myClass->myMethod();
```

Comment: Is this `if($result=$myClass->myMethod())` declaring the value within the `if` statement and then running the condition `if true`? If so it seems the perfect solution.

Comment: That's correct. It will return true if the value assigned to $result was not NULL/FALSE

Comment: The simplest one wouldn't work in my situation as there is a lot of html which is conditionally loaded via the initial if statement. I do currently use `simplest ` for single line `echo` statements where a condition isn't required other than the `echo` itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to reduce verbosity:

```
<?php

function foo($bool = true) {
    $result = array();
    if($bool) {
        $result = array('bar');
    }

    return $result;
}

if(! array()) {
    echo 'empty array evaluates to false.';
}

if($result = foo()) {
    var_export($result); // Will dump array with 'bar'.
}

if($result = foo(false)) {
    var_export($result); // Won't happen.
}
```

If your return is truish then the contents of the if will execute.